# Database returning " [object Object] " while using Javascript and SQL

Tags: javascript, sql

My database ( MS Access) continues returning [object Object] , almost as if there is no data there or as if it is unable to recognize the data I am requesting from it using SQL. It needs to display the data in a popup alter or window. I am just wandering why it is doing this and what I can do to correct it. The portion of my code that I'm using is as follows :

```
<button onclick="showscores(myDB)" style=" top: 155px; left: 160px; position: absolute;"> Show scores

var user = "Chad";
 // this is a global variable 


var myDB = new ACCESSdb("C:\\Users\\Kelly\\Users.mdb", {showErrors:true});// this is also global

function showscores(myDB){

// select and retrieve the complete user info data , containing the score data 
window.alert(myDB.query("SELECT * FROM userInfo "));
```

}

Comment: instead of `alert` use `console.log` and see if you see the data in the console

Comment: `"[object Object]"` is the default string representation of an object (just try `alert({foo: 'bar'})`). You need to access the properties on that object that are of interest to you. `alert` is **not** a debugging tool. There is no problem here except that you are not properly debugging your code.

Answer (score 1):

mate,check what you got from query by this:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(myDB.query("SELECT * FROM userInfo ")));
console.log(JSON.stringify(myDB.query("SELECT * FROM userInfo ")));
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that all is working as you are being returned an object. According to the [documentation](http://accessdb.sourceforge.net/)

"*By default, the record set of results is loaded into a **JavaScript Array object***"

The only other response would be false if there was an error so you now need to interact with the array to display / extract the information you want.